# Appropriate null hypothesis for rating a set of data points?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

My setup is this: I am generating some text (say 10 sentences) from a model in a particular scenario, and there’s some text generated by humans (10 sentences, same scenario). Each sentence (20 of them) is assessed by a group of experts who provide a score between 1-5. There are 30 such “scenarios”.

I want to test the hypothesis that the machine generated text quality is significantly better than the human generated text.

My original null hypothesis was that “the average quality of human generated text is significantly lower than the machine generated text”. Someone said that’s not a valid null hypothesis and a valid one would be “there’s no significant difference in the average quality of human generated text and machine generated text”.

I am wondering if mine is wrong or do I need to test the “no difference” hypothesis before the “greater” hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have:

$H_0$: There is no difference between human generated text and machine generated
and
$H_a$: There is a difference

or
$H_0$: Human generated text is not worse than machine generated text
and
$H_a$: Human generated text is worse

I would leave out "significant".  Your hypotheses are about differences. "Significance" is how you test the hypotheses.

Comment: So leaving out significant, both hypotheses are correct?

Comment: Either might be correct, depending on circumstances. In general, the first set would be preferred, because two tailed tests are, in general, preferred. But if you are *only* interested in one tail, that's OK, as long as you can justify your interest.

Comment: Being very, very nitpicky, the hypothesis "the average quality of human generated text is significantly lower than the machine generated text" does not map 100% on your question of interest that "the machine generated text quality is significantly better than the human generated text" because it does not exclude equality, while your content question is about being better, not being better or equal.

Comment: This might also be why someone told you the hypothesis is not valid, because in that case the null does not include equality.